# Is it possible to login from different domain

Tags: rest, session, authentication, authorization, microservices

Basically, I am trying to separate my User entity into micro-service for user account management. The app would provide a RESTful API for managing the user data. The question is, is it possible to login and authenticate the user on the user account management micro-service.
For instance, I would like to send my login credentials from my main app, which is running on port 8080 to micro-service running on 8081 port so that it would authenticate the user and redirect to home page of the main app.

Comment: Have a lokk her: https://jwt.io/

Comment: I tried JWT to authenticate and generate a token for the particular user but it lives in the user microservice. But now do I need to send that generated token back to the main app and create a session so that user can start using the main app? Is it even possible for such scenario?

Comment: If you use the token somewhere esle, you always have revalidate it against the auth server.

Comment: Would you give me a suggestion on what is better in this case? Does my user account management microservice is auth server now? How do I secure my main app if I move User entity completely from it?

Comment: I don't know your technology, maybe have a look here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: The legacy system is in Struts 1 which is already EOL so now I am trying to move the entities out bit by bit starting from User. I want to use Spring Boot to implement it.

Comment: than this should be your way to go

Comment: ok thank you @Torsten